# c# generic method with other generic type argument

Tags: c#, generics

I have 2 generic classes: `Db<E>`, `MR<T>`
I want to create a method which receives `Db<T>` and convert some fields in order to copy them or an `MR<E>` type.
E and T are 100% different when I use it.

so my method looks like:

```
public static MR<E> GetMRFromDb<E>(Db<T> db) 
                where E : class 
                where T : class
{

}
```

When I hover the `T` in the `where T : class` I'm warned with the following error:

> The type or namepsace name 'T' could not be found...

Both `MR` and `Db` are defined as generic classes.

Comment: That's because you didn't declare the generic `T` parameter. You are using it but never defining it.

Comment: You have to declare all the generic types for the method after the method name `GetMRFromDB<E,T>`

Comment: @juharr post as asnwer please, thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your method's signature to:

```
public static MR<E> GetMRFromDb<T,E>(Db<T> db)
      where T : class,
      where E : class
{
      // ...
}
```

Please note that this will impact on how you call this method.

Instead of this:

```
// db is of type Db<DbUser>
MR<User> mr = GetMRFromDb<User>(db);
```

It should be:

```
// db is of type Db<DbUser>
MR<User> mr = GetMRFromDb<DbUser, User>(db);
```